# Speeding up Solr Search By Split

Tags: solr, solr4

Hi i am looking to Speed up Solr searching.
To speed up the search, i am looking to split the search data.

My Site:
dating website has 1 million profiles 400k male and 600k female.

```
<document>
 <entity name="Boys">
 <entity name="Girls">
</document>
```

When I search using below query, then it will search in a million records.
A boy can search only girls, and a girl can search only boys.
Is there any way to search limited records as this will faster our search.

```
 solr/select?q=*:*&fq=some search
```

Comment: you can still use a filter query fq to filter only boys or girls. You can combine this with filterCache so it's already cached. An even better way is to use sharding, you can use solrCloud to save you some of the work, or you can just create two separate cores one for boys and one for girls.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

I have done the same thing using the core feature of solr.(version 3.3)

Which divides your index and restricts to a core only.

e.g I have 10 projects so I have created 10 cores and when I have to search for a specific project I send a request for that core only.

In your case you can create 2 core boys and girls.

Where in a boy logs in you can send a request to girl core and vice-versa.

so your search request would be

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/Core_name/select/?q=reference:test&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on
```

Comment: how do we implement core ? do you mean a separate solr instance for all projects ?

Comment: I have created a core by updating the solr.xml file. I didnt mean a separate solr instance. You can do this with a single solr instance. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CoreAdmin+API